# Logging page with jsp for spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I got this jsp for logging page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
.error {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
}

.msg {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #31708f;
    background-color: #d9edf7;
    border-color: #bce8f1;
}

#login-box {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>

    <h1>Spring Security Custom Login Form (Annotation)</h1>

    <div id="login-box">

        <h2>Login with Username and Password</h2>

        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
            <div class="error">${error}</div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
            <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
        </c:if>

        <form name='loginForm'
            action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>

            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='user' value=''></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>
                                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
                                </td>
            </tr>
           </table>

           <input type="hidden" 
                     name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(
        @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }
        model.setViewName("login");

        return model;

    }
```

and security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("{noop}123456").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')").and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll().failureUrl("/login?error").usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password").and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().csrf();

    }
}
```

After loggin I don't get valid url like: localhost/com.myproject.spring/login?error
or localhost/com.myproject.spring/admin
but I get always:
`localhost/com.myproject.spring/j_spring_security_check` and error message:  `The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`
What is wrong? I've just copied everything from this tutorial: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-custom-login-form-annotation-example/

Comment: Can you provide your security config?

Comment: Added on ya're command.

Comment: maybe this is becuz of my spring-security version? I got 5 and  i found that `the authentication process is /login which used to be /j_spring_security_check before Spring Security 4.`

Comment: At password {noop}123456  Why do you added {noop} part.

Comment: noop becuz of `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`? I have change `j_spring_security_check` to login and now is better: I get `localhost/com.myproject.spring/login?error` but I get this always even when password is good.